# Using Java 9 module system with Ant

Tags: ant, java-9, java-platform-module-system

I'm rather new to both Ant and the Java 9 module system, so please bear with me. I'm working on porting an existing Ant project over to use Java 9, and with that comes the use of modules.

In particular, right now I have 2 different modules, one which requires another, as follows:

```
../project/foo/src/org/bar/foo/module-info.java
module org.bar.foo {
    ...
    exports org.bar.foo
}

../project/baz/src/org/bar/baz/module-info.java
module org.bar.baz {
    requires org.bar.foo
}
```

During a build of `baz`, I receive an error: `module not found: org.bar.foo`.

After looking at [some examples](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start), I tried to set the `--module-path` through a compiler arg in the build file for `baz`, but I've had no luck thus far. I'm not too sure how specific/general I can be in specifying the module path.

Comment: "I'm not too sure how specific/general I can be in specifying the module path." ~> It suffices to name the folder that contains the `org.foo.bar` module.

Comment: @NicolaiParlog In the build file for `baz` I have `basedir="."`. Am I correct in using `--module-path ${basedir}/../foo`? I've tried going up one from there or down to the package folder, but I'm not having any luck.

Comment: I know next to nothing about Ant so I can't really help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my problem.

The `--module-path` flag should point to compiled (built) modules. In the case of Ant, this is the build directory.

For source files (what my initial question was trying to do), use `--module-source-path`.

More info available on the [module system JEP](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261).